# Place to put all association code in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Currently i put all my model association in entry point (index.js). I have BusinessTag and Tag models with belongsTo association, but when I use "include" to get the Tag from BusinessTag it always return "Tag is not associated with Business Tag".

When i move the association inside function right above the findAll() it works.
I have another project use the same approach (put all association in entry point) but everything is good.

```
//It's work
BusinessTag.belongsTo(Tag);

BusinessTag.findAll({include: [Tag]})
```

So, what is happening? where should i put all my association code with sequelize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for my question. First of all i'm not using migration, My application create table only depends on `sequelize.sync()`, that's the problem. Sometime `sequelize.sync` not generate table sequentially. So i suggest to always use database migrations if you want your association work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to follow the given sequence. it worked for me.

1. Define Data Models
2. Define Relationships (Associations)
3. Do generate models again. `sequalize.sync({force:true});` *Caution: this will delete your all current data and table.*

First try this code flow in index.js

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i do it all in sequence and not generate models again. But it doesnt work as usual. I have other project but it worked perfectly.

Comment: `sequalize.sync({force:false});` You can try this if you don't want to regenerate. Further check documentations.